# Rails: css not loading when running Rails server

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I run `rails s -e production` it works fine but when I go to view the page the css is not being loaded. I've made sure to add `config.assets.precompile += %w( crowdcode.css )` to `production.rb` and ran the command `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` before starting the server. I've been stuck on this and am not sure what to do.

Also the not_found template exists.

Here is what the server is logging.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-29 17:36:26 +0000
Processing by ReviewsController#index as HTML
  Rendered reviews/index.html.erb within layouts/application (33.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (2.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 89ms (Views: 87.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/assets/crowdcode-c312d7630b6588b5a99f361e3fab64bc.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-29 17:36:26 +0000
Processing by StaticController#not_found as CSS
  Parameters: {"a"=>"assets/crowdcode-c312d7630b6588b5a99f361e3fab64bc"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 36ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template static/not_found, application/not_found with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:css], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/ubuntu/Git/crowdcode/app/views"
):
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in `find'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `find_template'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:34:in `determine_template'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:10:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
  /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  sunspot_rails (2.0.0) lib/sunspot/rails/railties/controller_runtime.rb:15:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__92929331906777610__process_action__4197991901307476159__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3633207603625577106__call__2599388094366383915__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/deflater.rb:13:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'


Started GET "/assets/application-3e6c78ba3d0dce5818d812e2b87a8a7f.js" for 127.0.0.1 at     2013-08-29 17:36:26 +0000
Processing by StaticController#not_found as JS
  Parameters: {"a"=>"assets/application-3e6c78ba3d0dce5818d812e2b87a8a7f"}
  Rendered static/not_found.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-29 17:36:28 +0000
Processing by ReviewsController#index as HTML
  Rendered reviews/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/assets/crowdcode-c312d7630b6588b5a99f361e3fab64bc.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-29 17:36:28 +0000
Processing by StaticController#not_found as CSS
  Parameters: {"a"=>"assets/crowdcode-c312d7630b6588b5a99f361e3fab64bc"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
```

Comment: Did you do rake assets:precompile?

Comment: @uDaY Yea I did. I put the commands I ran that I thought would be of interest in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the file `config/production.rb`

from:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

to:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

This may fix your issue and after this don't forget to precomplie your assets.

Hope this should work. :-)